# Does $L=K(\theta)$ implies that $\hat{\mathscr{O}_L}=\hat{\mathscr{O}_K}(\theta)$?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a Dedekind ring, $K=\operatorname{Frac}A$, $L/K$ a finite separable extension and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. (Perhaps we should suppose that $K$ is a global field.)

Each non-zero prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Spec}A$ determines an absolute value $|\cdot|_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of $K$ and each prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}\in\operatorname{Spec}B$ over $\mathfrak{p}$ determines an absolute value $|\cdot|_{\mathfrak{P}}$ of $L$ which extends $|\cdot|_{\mathfrak{p}}$. We denote $\hat{K}$ and $\hat{L}$ the completions of $K$ and $L$ with respect to their respective absolute values.

We also denote $\hat{A}$ the valuation ring of $\hat{K}$ (which coincides with the completion of $A$ and the closure of $A$ in $\hat{K}$) and $\hat{B}$ the valuation ring of $\hat{L}$ (which coincides with the completion of $B$, the closure of $B$ in $\hat{L}$ and the integral closure of $\hat{A}$ in $\hat{L}$).

If $L=K(\theta)$ for some $\theta\in L$, I understand that $\hat{L}=\hat{K}(\theta)$. But I also know that $\hat{B}=\hat{A}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha$. **I wonder if we can take $\alpha=\theta$.** If not, how can we calculate $\hat{B}$? I'm having trouble calculating it even in the simplest cases (for example when $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(i)$).

Comment: The different $\mathfrak{p}$-adic completions of $L$ are the $K_\mathfrak{p}(\theta_i)$ for each root $\theta_i\in \overline{K_\mathfrak{p}}$ of the minimal polynomial $f\in K[x]$ of $\theta$. Finding the DVR of the completions is another more complicated problem. For number fields $p\in \mathfrak{p}$ then you can take $\alpha = b_j^p+\pi_j$ where $O_L/\mathfrak{P}_j=O_K/\mathfrak{p}[\alpha]$ and $(p,\pi_j) = \mathfrak{P}_j$.

Comment: @reuns let me see if I understood your comment: the different $\mathfrak{p}$-adic completions of $L$ correspond precisely to the choice of the prime $\mathfrak{P}$ over $\mathfrak{p}$, isn't it? In this case, how can we relate the choice of a root $\theta_i$ to the choice of $\mathfrak{P}$? Also, what is $b_j$?

Comment: I meant $O_L/\mathfrak{P}_j=O_K/\mathfrak{p}[b_j]$. There is a natural embedding $K(\theta)\to K_\mathfrak{p}(\theta_i)$, so it gives a discrete valuation on $L$ and the elements of $O_L$ having valuation $>0$ is our prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}_j$. Another $\theta_l$ gives the same prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}_j$ iff it is $K_\mathfrak{p}$ conjugate to $\theta_i$ (when $L/K$ is Galois this is the decomposition group $D(\mathfrak{P}_j/\mathfrak{p})$).

Comment: Once again, let me see if I understood it well in the simple case $L=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}$. Lets take $p=2$ and $\mathfrak{P}=(1+i)$. In this case we have that $\hat{L}=\mathbb{Q}_2(i)$. Also $\mathscr{O}_L/\mathfrak{P}=\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)=\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ so we can take $b=1$ and $\pi=1+i$. Then this implies that $\hat{\mathbb{Z}[i]}=\mathbb{Z}_2[2+i]=\mathbb{Z}_2[i]$?

Comment: @reuns Also, do you know some reference where I can see the proof of everything you've told me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L=K(\theta)$ an finite extension of number field.

A completion $L_Q$ above $K_P$ gives an embedding $h:K(\theta)\to \overline{K_P}$, it maps $\theta$ to a root $h(\theta)$ of $f\in K[x]$ the minimal polynomial of $\theta$.

$h(L)=K(h(\theta))$ is dense in $K_P(h(\theta))$ and the latter is complete so $L_Q=K_P(h(\theta))$.

Then we look at $O_{L_Q}$ the closure of $O_L$ in $L_Q$. The main theorem is that it is a DVR, with uniformizer $(\pi_Q)$. Take some $b_Q\in O_L$ such that $O_L/(\pi_Q)=O_L/Q=(O_K/P)[b_Q+P]$. Let $S_Q$ be some representatives in $O_K[b_Q]$ of the residue field $O_L/Q$. By definition of a complete DVR $$O_{L_Q} = \{ \sum_{n\ge 0} s_n \pi_Q^n, s_n\in S_Q\}= \sum_{j=0}^{f(Q/P)-1} b_Q^j \sum_{m=0}^{e(Q/P)-1} \pi_Q^m O_{K_P}=O_{K_P}[b_Q,\pi_Q]$$
It works the same way when replacing $b_Q$ by $b_Q^p+\pi_Q$ and $\pi_Q$ by $(b_Q^p+\pi_Q)^{N(Q)-1}-1$ (prove that the latter is an uniformizer if $p$ isn't an uniformizer) thus $$O_{L_Q} = O_{K_P}[b_Q^p+\pi_Q]$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer @reuns. The only thing I still don't understand is the equality $\{ \sum_{n\ge 0} s_n \pi_Q^n, s_n\in S_Q\}= \sum_{j=0}^{f(Q/P)-1} b_Q^j \sum_{m=0}^{e(Q/P)-1} \pi_Q^m O_{K_P}$. Could you explain why that holds?

Comment: If I say $O_{L_Q}=\{ \sum_{n\ge 0} s_n \pi_Q^n, s_n\in S_{Q,n}\}$ where $S_Q$ now depends on $n$, we are allowed to change our representatives of the residue field at each $n$, then decomposing $O_{K,P} =\{ \sum_{n\ge 0} z_n \pi_P^n,z_n\in Z_P\}$ puts the RHS in the desired form

Comment: The RHS is a fundamental formula, it shows $[L_Q:K_P] = ef$